# Susy: Syntax error: Undefined operation: "1/0.623em times 1em"

Tags: susy-compass

Trying to use susy with [middlemanapp](http://middlemanapp.com/) and getting the following error after the basic setup

```
Syntax error: Undefined operation: "1/0.623em times 1em"
        on line 32 of .... /gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/typography/_vertical_rhythm.scss
        etc.
        etc.
```

Info:

```
gem "middleman", "~>3.0.7"
gem "susy", "~> 1.0.5"

$ ruby -v ====> ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
```

_grid.scss

```
@import "susy";

$total-columns  : 12;
$column-width   : 60px;
$gutter-width   : 20px;
$grid-padding   : $gutter-width;


.container { @include container; }
```

Comment: can you paste the offending code, please?

Comment: The offending code really isn't anything special, it's literally just the basic setup. i.e. .container { @include container; }

Comment: What are your grid settings?

Comment: updated the original post with the contents of my grid file. Thank's by the way.

Comment: Actually, the error you are getting is from compass vertical_rhythm module. That's interesting. Do you have any other imports or settings in your scss? Can you paste the full error, including the "etc. etc." parts?

Comment: I went to turn all the susy stuff back on to generate the error and it appears to be working fine. Can't really think what's different but it's working.

Comment: At the risk of looking REALLY dumb commenting on this topic AFTER @Eric Meyer did, did you not define a base0font-size? Maybe that's where compass' typographic errors were coming in?